# How to compile and execute multiple TypeScript modules with single entry point, to a single file

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings, amd, systemjs, system.js

For some reason, I find myself in a situation where I need to compile one file (main entry point), which depends on multiple other modules in other files, into a single-bundle-file. It must be able to run in the browser.

I must use the TypeScript compiler, and only that tool (i.e. not Webpack, Babel, etc.).

I am currently compiling using the --outFile option with --module set to either *System* or *AMD* (which are the only ones allowed for --outFile).

For System, something along the lines of the following gets generated:

```
[some more modules ...]

System.register("index", [...], function (exports, context) {
    [...]
});
```

When I try to stick this in an HTML file like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/6.1.7/system.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    [some more modules ...]

    System.register("index", [...], function (exports, context) {
        [...]
    });
    System.import("index").then(function (m) {
        new m.run();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get:

```
Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'index' from [...]
```

What am I doing wrong with System?
Also, which is better for my purpose? AMD or System?

Comment: Any joy? I asked this question and answered my own. Sounds like you want to accomplish what I was doing? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497363/405022