# Resolving typescript modules in the browser yields a 404

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am looking to put together a small example of for a web app that is created using `typescript`.  I have an issue with importing a module.

I just want information on why this is wrong and what options I have to sort it.

The problem is a 404 for the in the index.js file when trying to import the hello.

Here is the code:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Check the console log...</p>
    </body>

    <script type="module" src="/dist/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

### index.ts

```
import { HelloWorld } from "./hello";

var helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

helloWorld.sayHello();
```

### hello.ts

```
export class HelloWorld {
    constructor() {

    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2015",
      "module": "ES2015",
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "moduleResolution": "node",

      "allowJs": true,
      "checkJs": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
  }
```

The output of the above using `tsc` to compile the app is as follows:

```
dist
    hello.js
    hello.js.map
    index.js
    index.js.map
```

These are as follows:

### hello.js

```
export class HelloWorld {
    constructor() {
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log("Hello, world!");
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=hello.js.map
```

### index.js

```
import { HelloWorld } from "./hello";
var helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
helloWorld.sayHello();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Now if I change the `index.ts` to the full `hello.js` instead of `hello` then this will work.  This feels wrong - as there is no `index.js` whilst I am coding this.

What is the correct way of resolving this to run in an `ES2015` compatible browser such as Chrome?

Do I have to use something such as `requirejs`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `import h from './hello.js'` in your typescript.
Also read this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577

Comment: thats what I said at the end of the post... but it doesnt feel right.  Will check link thanks

Comment: this worked for me, but I agree it doesn't feel quite right. It's strange that in the TS docs they do not specify .js but in the import statement but I nonetheless have to specify it in my .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a module loader such as [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).  Looking at the [example](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs-examples/tree/master/loading-code/typescript-default-extension) they provided it shows you how to achieve this without changing your typescript imports.

With the above example you can make the following changes:

### index.html

Add script reference to systemjs.

Use the systemjs import javascript syntax to load the index module.  No extension required.

Add the script reference to import a resolver (resolve.js) which is required to load extensionless javascript files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/6.3.1/system.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-15j2fw0zp8UuYXmubFHW7ScK/xr5NhxkxmJcp7T3Lrc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./dist/systemjs-hooks/resolve.js"></script>
    <script>System.import("./dist/index")</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Check the console log...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

### resolve.ts

Taken from the systemjs example.

```
(function () {
    const endsWithFileExtension = /\/?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    const originalResolve = System.constructor.prototype.resolve;
    System.constructor.prototype.resolve = function () {
      // apply original resolve to make sure importmaps are resolved first
      const url = originalResolve.apply(this, arguments);
      // append .js file extension if url is missing a file extension
      return endsWithFileExtension.test(url) ? url : url + ".js";
    };
  })();
```

## tsconfig.json

Change the `module` to `system`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2015",
      "module": "system",
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "moduleResolution": "node",

      "allowJs": true,
      "checkJs": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
  }
```

### index.js output

You can see you get a completely different output with the `module` set to `system`.

```
System.register(["./hello"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var hello_1, helloWorld;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (hello_1_1) {
                hello_1 = hello_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            helloWorld = new hello_1.HelloWorld();
            helloWorld.sayHello();
        }
    };
});
```

### package.json

We need to bring in some additional `devDependencies` to use system in the `resolve.ts`.

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "foo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/systemjs": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```